# My links inside of my coding files wont work

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have been working on this project and I have been using images and linking my css files now that I have actually uploaded the site to the web/internet none on the link href="" rel="stylesheet" (css files) and 
img are connected anymore. I think I made a rookie mistake by linking using link href=**"user/macbook/desktop/folder/imgs/logo"** basically going to deep into the registry. Now I'm faced with going through 100 pages of code to reorganize everything is their a quick fix???

example of my current css linking

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/Users/macbook/Desktop/prov 
brand/css/corporaterec.css">
```

it goes to deep into my computers registry that when I uploaded through ftp it does not find the css file

Comment: I don't even understand the problem. Please read [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: so I updated if you can understand now

Comment: `sed` can be used to perform automatic text processing: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, always keep a backup of your css file. Secondly, the example link you gave seems to be in a folder on the desktop of your mac (it wouldn't be in the registry)

Your folder will have a new path now that you have uploaded it to a server via ftp. To correct your error, you should locate the css file on your server, and then replace your current path with the correct server path, then your pages will work.

If you still have the "hundreds of files" that include an incorrect file path to the spreadsheet stored locally, you can use find/replace to replace the wrong path with the correct path and then ftp the files again (which doesn't take long.. ftp is quick).

Best of luck.